# os x lion macport problem

Tags: macos, macports, osx-lion

I'm trying to install tomcat6 on OS X Lion using via macport 2.0. However, there is problem during the installation of one of the dependencies "commons-dbcp"

The messages are as follows

```
--->  Building commons-dbcp
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
Error: Failed to install commons-dbcp
```

After upgrading my OS to Lion, this kind of problem with macport happens alot and I don't know how to fix. It stopped me from installing a number of packages which I could install without a problem on Snow leopard.

Anyone could help me on this? Thanks

Comment: did you perform a "sudo port selfupdate" ?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't help. Still having the same prob

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have XCode 4.1+ installed and then update (re-install) your MacPorts to version 2.0.0
more instruction available [here](http://www.macports.org/install.php).

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem,  As pointed by Shayanlinux, installing XCode 4.1+ and running a sudo port selfupdate fixed the problem.